# Swift 3 Core Data issue - All Data Missing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I upgraded my Core Data project from Swift 2 to Swift 3. Replace the Core Data stack with `NSPersistentContainer`. But the new version can't find old data.

[image: Swift 2 Version]

after new version installed:

[image: Swift 3 Version]

**Swift 3 Version app can't find any data**

My app's function is to record words/sentences and their Chinese meaning.If I release this version on the App Store, users will lose all their records after updating.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my Swift 3 code:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "social.street.NewWords" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "NewWords", withExtension: "momd")!
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NewWords", managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!)

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)

    let storeUrl = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")

    print(storeUrl)

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeUrl)]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as? NSError {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Swift 2 Code:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "social.street.NewWords" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("NewWords", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

How to remain data after code upgraded to Swift 3?

in addition: swift 2 version is installed from the App Store, and swift 3 version is installed from the Xcode.

[Project's Github repo](https://github.com/josephchang10/NewWords)

Comment: did you log the modelURL, container, storeUrl etc. ? do they stay the same as the Swift 2 version?

Comment: I can't find Swift 2 version's log. But as you can see, my code of modelURL, storeUrl are same as the previous version.

Comment: Have you implemented light weight migration ? I believe this should fix the issue, if you add / remove / change properties from one version to the next of the app you have to implement light weight migration so that that app can  modify the DB instead of replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implemented light weight mirgration?

when you initialise your persistent store you can add 'Options', for light weight migration add:

```
let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                     NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
```

Then when you change the DB on each app version first you must go to the .xcdatamodel and go to:

```
'editor' > 'Add Model Version'
```

In the top menu, then make your changes to this version and make sure it has the green tick on when you open up the model.

Comment: I use `let storeOptions: [String:Any] = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:"CloudNewWordsStore",NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true]`. It worked! Thanks, you saved me.

Comment: Glad to be of some help :D